# Counting Amount of Files in Directory Including Hidden Files with BASH

Tags: linux, bash

I want to count the amount of files in the directory I am currently in (including hidden files). So far I have this:

```
ls -1a | wc -l
```

but I believe this returns 2 more than what I want because it also counts "." (current directory) and ".." (directory above this one) as files. How would I go about returning the correct amount of files?

Comment: I think this should get migrated to superuser..com

Comment: @Frerich it's almost certainly a duplicate there though.

Answer (score 4):

I believe to count all files / directories / hidden file you can also use BASH array like this:

```
shopt -s nullglob dotglob

cd /whatever/path
arr=( * )
count="${#arr[@]}"
```

This also works with filenames that contain space or newlines.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

`ls` piped to `wc` is not the right tool for that job. This is because filenames in UNIX can contain newlines as well. This would lead to counting them multiple times.

Following @gniourf_gniourf's comment (thanks!) the following command will handle newlines in file names correctly and should be used:

```
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf x | wc -c
```

The `find` command lists files in the current directory - including hidden files, excluding the `.` and `..` because of `-mindepth 1`. It works non-recursively because of `-maxdepth 1`.

The `-printf x` action simply prints an `x` for each file in the directory which leads to an output like this:

```
xxxxxxxx
```

Piped to `wc -c` (`-c` means counting characters) you get your final result.

---

**Former Answer:**

Use the following command:

```
ls -1A | wc -l
```

`-a` will include all files or directories starting with a dot, but `-A` will exclude the current folder `.` and the parent folder `..`

I suggest to follow [`man ls`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls)

Comment: If you have GNU goodies, I would suggest: `find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf x | wc -c`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I've added that to my answer. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @Blobert I've added explanation for the `find` command. Is it clear now?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, hek2mgl. I understand it now. Also, thanks for the previous answer Maxim Egorushkin .

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right:

```
ls -1A | wc -l
```

If you filenames contain new-lines or other funny characters do:

```
find -type f -ls | wc -l
```

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I did what you suggested. Still my code works as expected.

Comment: “Works for me” doesn't mean it works for everybody, does it? though, I really doubt it works for you…

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Well, you have not demonstrated how it breaks.

Comment: `mkdir gniourf_test; cd gniourf_test; touch $'a\nb'; ls -1A | wc -l` will happily (and wrongly answer 2).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf If you'd like to shoot yourself in the foot, then go nuts. http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html

Comment: `find -type f -ls | wc -l` isn't really equivalent: it only counts regular files (whereas—it seems—OP wants to counts all files (pipes, dirs, etc.)), it's recursive (OP doesn't want to recurse), and it counts `.` too (and that was one of OP's problems).

Comment: Regarding the link you post: I completely disagree. There are well-known techniques to handle in a 100% safe way any character in filenames. Only ignorant people would add restrictions on filenames, **so that these restrictions fit their broken methods**. I'm sorry, I can't support that.

Comment: I agree. Also it is part of the UNIX philosophy to allow you to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf It is not clear what you disagree with. That link explains in details how to handle filenames with special characters. You can be diligent in how you handle such filenames, or you can just skip the complexity by avoiding such characters in you filenames. KISS is also a part UNIX philosophy.

Comment: I only disagree with putting restrictions on filenames. Now you're right, the article explains how to handle filenames with funny characters, and is actually pretty good and thorough! though, I really don't want to have any restrictions on my system just because of dumb users. Bash and GNU have made tremendous efforts to actually be able to handle any character in filenames (arrays, `-d` delimiter to `read`, etc. in Bash, the null-terminating fields widely supported with GNU tools, etc.). And come one, how could you seriously avoid spaces in filenames today?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Depends on your problem domain. Users often create documents with funny characters in their filenames. Built system and batch jobs often are designed to produce only well-behaved names for directories and filenames. I prefer adding complexity only where it is warranted.

Comment: I think this discussion (though interesting) is a bit flawed since we don't necessarily talk about the same domain of application. I'm just a fervent advocate of robust methods to handle any filename in any situation. Whatever `:)`. Though, your `find` command here doesn't quite fulfill OP's requirement: recursion, `-type f`, and (I'm being picky and pedantic), `-ls` is not semantically correct here (though it does the job alright).